# How do you exclude a string from a Regular Expression so that if the string is present on a line of text, it will not return a match?

Tags: regex

I know that a similar question to this has been asked before but I couldn't get that solution to work. It's this one

[Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Here's the text

```
     ID   Type    Code    Test Name                  Dept    Date --- Time --- By
 ---- ---- ---------- ------------------------- ------ -------- --------

 01     S  10231AB=,+ Test1 With Spaces       20180913  1:08 AM ENIG01
 02     S  %SBTEX1    Test2 With Spaces       20180912 10:02 AM MYR001
 03     B  6399AB=    Test3 With Spaces       20180912 12:07 AM WDHLSY1
 04     S  4848AB=,4+ Test4 With Spaces       20180912 12:07 AM WDHLSY1
 05     S  899AB=,+   TSH+                    20180913  1:08 AM ENIG01
 06     S  899AB=,+   TSH+
```

Lines 1 and 2 are not a match because the contain the text "10231" and "%SBTEX1".

Line 5 is the match.

Line 6 is not a match because it does not have a string of digits such as "20180913" followed by the date and time.

I tried but could not even come up with a regular expression that matched all of the lines of code except for line 6.

Here's the Regex that is in the post mentioned above. It excludes a line of code that contains a word.

```
^((?!hede).)*$
```

The Question:

A big shout out to Wiktor Stribiżew who solved my original question. But I had omitted some text and when I tried to implement his solution, I realized the problem was more complicated than I had initially thought.

If you would like to see his solution to the original question, please visit the link below.

[Wiktor's Solution To The Original Question](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%5Cd%2B%5Cs%2B%5Cw%5Cs%2B%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3C!%5Cs%28%3F%3A10231%7C91431%29%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=01%20%20%20%20%20S%20%2010231%0D%0A02%20%20%20%20%20S%20%2091431%0D%0A03%20%20%20%20%20S%20%20899&o=m)

Wiktor if you could. Please post your solution on RegexStorm.Net/Tester again, that was amazing!

Thank you,

Mark S.

Comment: Try [`(?m)(?>^[\t\p{Zs}]*\d+\s+\w\s+\S+)(?<!\s\S*(?<!\d)(?:10231|%SBTEX1)(?!\d)\S*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3e%5e%5b%5ct%5cp%7bZs%7d%5d*%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%5cw%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%29%28%3f%3c!%5cs%5cS*%28%3f%3c!%5cd%29%28%3f%3a10231%7c%25SBTEX1%29%28%3f!%5cd%29%5cS*%29&i=+01+++++S++10231AB%3d%2c%2b+Test1%0d%0a+02+++++S++%25SBTEX1++++Test2+With+Spaces+++++++20180912+10%3a02+AM+MYR001%0d%0a+03+++++B++6399AB%3d++++Test3%0d%0a+04+++++S++4848AB%3d%2c4%2b+Test4%0d%0a+05+++++S++899AB%3d%2c%2b+++TSH%2b+%0d%0a+06+++++S++899AB%3d%2c%2b+++TSH%2b++&o=m). I am a bit unsure of the rule here.

Comment: Maybe just [`(?m)(?>^\s*\d+\s+\w\s+\S+)(?<!(?:10231|%SBTEX1)\S*)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%28%3f%3e%5e%5cs*%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%5cw%5cs%2b%5cS%2b%29%28%3f%3c!%28%3f%3a10231%7c%25SBTEX1%29%5cS*%29&i=+01+++++S++10231AB%3d%2c%2b+Test1%0d%0a+02+++++S++%25SBTEX1++++Test2+With+Spaces+++++++20180912+10%3a02+AM+MYR001%0d%0a+03+++++B++6399AB%3d++++Test3%0d%0a+04+++++S++4848AB%3d%2c4%2b+Test4%0d%0a+05+++++S++899AB%3d%2c%2b+++TSH%2b+%0d%0a+06+++++S++899AB%3d%2c%2b+++TSH%2b++&o=m)?

Comment: I added to the second one that you posted. We almost have it but it is counting line 4 instead of line 5. How can we specify to stop at the line end?                                                                                                         (?m)(?>^[\t\p{Zs}]*\d+\s+S\s+\S+)(?<!\s\S*(?<!\d)(?:10231|%SBTEX1)(?!\d)\S*)\s+\w+.+\d+\s+\d

Comment: On a match, the line will end with an ID such as "WDHLSY1"

Comment: Sorry, I do not get what you mean. To match end of a line, use `\r?$`. Remember to replace `\s` with `[\p{Zs}\t]` if you want to stay on a line while matching.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(?m)^\d+\s+\w\s+\d+(?<!\s(?:10231|91431))\r?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%5cw%5cs%2b%5cd%2b%28%3f%3c!%5cs%28%3f%3a10231%7c91431%29%29%5cr%3f%24&i=01+++++S++10231%0d%0a02+++++S++91431%0d%0a03+++++S++899&o=m).

I assume the lines do not start with whitespaces, so I removed the initial `\s+` from your pattern and added the `^` as a start of a line anchor (as `(?m)` modifies the behavior of both `^` and `$`, thus, making `\r?` necessary for `$` to match at the CRLF line endings.)

**Pattern details**

- `(?m)` - `^` now matches the start of a line and `$` matches the end of a line
- `^` - start of a line
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (replace with `[\p{Zs}\t]+` to only match horizontal whitespaces (`[^\S\r\n]+` might also do))
- `\w` - a word char
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?<!\s(?:10231|91431))` - a **negative lookbehind** that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a whitespace and either of the two numeric values
- `\r?$` - an optional CR and end of a line anchor.

Comment: It's really good but I probably should have included the full text. I'm trying it on the text that I'm really trying to find the answer to and I can't get it to work. I'll study your answer tomorrow and see if I can get it to work. If not, I'll post the entire text and you'll probably be able to get it. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @MarkS: The main point is to find the place where you may "anchor" the restricting lookaround and then use the lookaround (if a lookahead, it must be in front,  a lookbehind, as you see, is after the more generic pattern). The same can be achieved with [`(?m)^\d+\s+\w\s+(?!(?:10231|91431)\r?$)\d+\r?$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%5cd%2b%5cs%2b%5cw%5cs%2b%28%3f!%28%3f%3a10231%7c91431%29%5cr%3f%24%29%5cd%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=01+++++S++10231%0d%0a02+++++S++91431%0d%0a03+++++S++899&o=m).

Comment: What if I need to keep going with the regular expression? Can I keep adding to it after the look behind?

Comment: @MarkS Yes, try. Let know if you have issues.

Comment: I updated the question Wiktor. I came into work this morning and have been trying for an hour but this problem is beyond my skills with Regex unfortunately. I believe you'll be able to figure it out. Thank you in advance for your support!

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this particular problem is:

```
(?m)(?>^[\t\p{Zs}]*\d+\s+S\s+\S+)(?<!\s\S*(?<!\d)(?:10231|%SBTEX1)(?!\d)\S*).+\d+[\p{Zs}\t]+\d+
```

Click the hyperlink below to be taken to this solution on RegexStorm.Net/Tester so you can mess around with the Regex yourself for learning purposes.

[Interactive Solution On RegexStorm.Net/Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%28%3F%3E%5E%5B%5Ct%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5D*%5Cd%2B%5Cs%2BS%5Cs%2B%5CS%2B%29%28%3F%3C!%5Cs%5CS*%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%28%3F%3A10231%7C%25SBTEX1%29%28%3F!%5Cd%29%5CS*%29.%2B%5Cd%2B%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D%2B%5Cd%2B&i=%20ID%20%20%20Type%20%20%20%20Code%20%20%20%20Test%20Name%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Dept%20%20%20%20Date%20---%20Time%20---%20By%0D%0A%20----%20----%20----------%20-------------------------%20------%20--------%20--------%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%2001%20%20%20%20%20S%20%2010231AB%3D%2C%2B%20Test1%20With%20Spaces%20%20%20%20%20%20%2020180913%20%201%3A08%20AM%20ENIG01%0D%0A%2002%20%20%20%20%20S%20%20%25SBTEX1%20%20%20%20Test2%20With%20Spaces%20%20%20%20%20%20%2020180912%2010%3A02%20AM%20MYR001%0D%0A%2003%20%20%20%20%20B%20%206399AB%3D%20%20%20%20Test3%20With%20Spaces%20%20%20%20%20%20%2020180912%2012%3A07%20AM%20WDHLSY1%0D%0A%2004%20%20%20%20%20S%20%204848AB%3D%2C4%2B%20Test4%20With%20Spaces%20%20%20%20%20%20%2020180912%2012%3A07%20AM%20WDHLSY1%0D%0A%2005%20%20%20%20%20S%20%20899AB%3D%2C%2B%20%20%20TSH%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2020180913%20%201%3A08%20AM%20ENIG01%0D%0A%2006%20%20%20%20%20S%20%20899AB%3D%2C%2B%20%20%20TSH%2B%20%20%20%20%20%20)

This will match lines 4 and lines 5 which is what I wanted. Originally I had

```
(?m)(?>^[\t\p{Zs}]*\d+\s+S\s+\S+)(?<!\s\S*(?<!\d)(?:10231|%SBTEX1)(?!\d)\S*).+\d+\s+\d+
```

Which was only matching line 4. I read Wiktor's comment and he said

```
"Remember to replace \s with [\p{Zs}\t] if you want to stay on a line while matching."
```

So I then replaced the \s+ at the end of this Regex with [\p{Zs}\t]+ and got the answer that will work for my particular problem. One more time, it is:

```
(?m)(?>^[\t\p{Zs}]*\d+\s+S\s+\S+)(?<!\s\S*(?<!\d)(?:10231|%SBTEX1)(?!\d)\S*).+\d+[\p{Zs}\t]+\d+
```

I would also encourage anyone who needs to exclude any string of text from being a match in a Regex to manipulate this solution to your own needs.

Thank you Wiktor. I couldn't have gotten this solution without your help!